# Why won't ASPX display my XML?

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml

I have a ASPX page that I am trying to use to display some XML.

Here is my ASPX page,

```
%@ Page Language="C#" %>

<%@ Import Namespace="System.IO" %>
<%@ Import Namespace="System.Xml" %>

<script runat="server">
  protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
    string theXML = Server.MapPath("~/sample.xml");
    lit1.Text = root.SelectSingleNode("author").ChildNodes[0].Value;
  }
</script>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
  <title>Untitled Page</title>
</head>
<body>
  <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
      <pre>
        <asp:Literal ID="lit1" runat="server" />
      </pre>
    </div>
  </form>
</body>
</html>
```

And here is my XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<article>
    <author>Faisal Khan</author>
    <title>Sample XML Document</title>
    <body>The body of the article goes here.</body>
</article>
```

When I try and view the page, IIS gives me an error:

> Server Error in '/' Application.
>
> Configuration Error

I am really not sure what is causing this. `sample.xml` is in my root directory, this is on localhost.

Comment: If you see "Server Error" that almost certainly means an exception is being thrown. You should examine the logs to find out what. I *suspect* it's because you're using `~sample.xml` instead of `~/sample.xml` but you should learn how to find errors before you fix this particular one - the next one may be harder to discover.

Comment: Have you tried setting the Literal control's property "Mode" to "Encode"? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.literal.mode(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Investigated and changed both of these. Still the same error...

Comment: I'm going to assume there is some code missing here, since I don't see where `root` is defined.

Comment: Did you get more information about the specific error?